# Angular2 FormArray - Display textarea character count on page - how?

Tags: angular

I would like to display the character count for each textarea element in a FormArray.

This is what I have. Don't see a way to use indexes or dynamically make a unique local variable name, where I currently have the `alocalname` placeholders, to get what I want. How can I do this.

```
<div class="list-group" formArrayName="texts">
   <div class="row"
     *ngFor="let text of profileForm.controls['texts'].controls; let i = index;">
       <div formGroupName="{{i}}">
          <div>
            <textarea type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="text" #alocalname></textarea>
            <small class="form-text text-muted"><code>{{alocalname.value.length}}</code> of characters</small>
        </div>          
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to access the value from each `control` that you're iterating.

So `text.get('text').value.length` should work.

```
<div class="list-group" formArrayName="texts">
   <div class="row"
     *ngFor="let text of profileForm.get('texts').controls; let i = index;">
       <div [formGroupName]="i">
          <div>
            <textarea type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="text"></textarea>
            <small class="form-text text-muted"><code>{{text.get('text').value.length}}</code> of characters</small>
        </div>          
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: For those confused by 'text' everywhere, if it were: let v of profileForm.get('videos') ...  And the formControlName was videoText. Then the answer would be <code>{{v.get('videoText').value.length}}</code>